# BarButtonItemに適用したAsset Catalog画像がスケールしない

Tags: ios

以前に以下のサイトのベストアンサーを参考にnavigationBarのbarbuttonitemにasset catalogの画像を適用するコードを実装して、うまく動いていました。
　[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473359/image-for-nav-bar-button-item-swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31473359/image-for-nav-bar-button-item-swift?answertab=votes#tab-top)
　先日、Xcode10.0でDeployment targetを10.3でビルドしたところ、スケーリングが正常に行われず、navigationBarいっぱいに広がった画像が表示されてしまいました。同じアプリで通常のUIButtonなどにもasset catalogから画像を適用していますが、そっちは正常に表示されているので、barbuttonitemだけの問題じゃないかと思っています。
　何か修正が必要になったのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[iOS 11 UIBarButtonItem images not sizing - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46247451/ios-11-uibarbuttonitem-images-not-sizing)

上記ページに回答が付いていました。要するに最近のiOSでは、barButtonItemはframeではなくautolayoutで制御する必要があると。